# RegExp for floating point

Tags: java, regex

I want a regular expression which accepts the following values:

- 01 (no dot)
- 01.0 (1 digit after dot)
- 01.00 (2 digits after dot)

And doesn't accept the following:

- 10.(No digits after dot)
- 10.001 (3 digits after dot)

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be something like this: `[0-9]*(\.[0-9]{1,2})?`

Where the `{1,2}` stands for 1-2 digits after the dot.

Comment: Are you sure you want that forward slash in the character set?

Comment: @Matzi, thanks for your quick reply. What if my minimum & maximum digits after dot are dynamic?

Comment: @Matzi, once again thanks for your quick reply. This regex works for me.

Answer (score 2):

One possible regex would be

```
\d*([.]\d{1,2})?
```

This will match zero or more digits and then an optional group that contains a dot and one or two digits.

Comment: @murgatroid99: -1, Haven't you forget to escape the decimal point over there?

Comment: Within a character set, `.` doesn't do anything special, so it doesn't need to be escaped

Comment: @murgatroid99:+1, Oh! dint notice. My apologies.