# When I input numeric , it also detect it as incorrect format

Tags: javascript

```
 function checkAge(form)          /* for age validation */
 {
    var eobj=document.getElementById('ageerror');
    var age = form.age.value;
    var oR =/[0-9,.]+/;
    eobj.innerHTML='';

    if (age == '') {
       error='Error: Age cannot be blank!';
       form.age.focus();
    }
    else if (!oR.test(age))
    {
       error='Incorrect format!'
    }
    if (error)
    {
       form.age.focus();
       eobj.innerHTML=error;
       return false;
    }
}
```

1. var oR =/[0-9,.]+/;
2. else if (!oR.test(age))

something error at this part?

hopefully someone can help me solve the problem,thx!

Comment: What have you entered? Maybe there are some spaces.

Comment: paste browser error too.

Comment: You probably want your regular expression to be `/^[0-9,.]+$/` so that it only allows numbers, not letters as well.

Comment: you need sth like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10739092/regexp-for-floating-point, bcz your regexp is not complete. I do not know what exactly you are trying to validate. If age is a floating value ,check the previous link. as @dystory suggested init `error` variable also

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add

```
var error;
```

at the start of your function so that the error is reinitialized.

Right now, as the variable is global, it's never cleaned if it failed once.